# My result keeps showing my numbers as a minus or negative number instead of a whole number

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Please i'm a beginner so forgive me in advance if my question isn't making sense.

My result keeps showing my numbers as a minus or negative number instead of a whole number see screenshot image attached

[My Code console log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzc5D.png)

My Code

```
const bookName = prompt(`name of book?`);
const bookPageNum = prompt(`How many pages does your book have?`);
const bookPageReadToday = prompt(`How many pages did you read today?`);
const bookDailyLimit = 10;

console.log(bookName);
console.log(bookPageNum);

const bookCalc = (a, b, c, d) => {
    if (c - d === 0 || c > d) {
        console.log(`You have read your daily limit today for your book called ${a}, Well DONE!! you have ${c - b} left to read in total`);
    } else if (b - c > 0) {
        console.log(`you still have ${c - d} pages left to read today and ${c - b} pages to read in total.`);
    } else {
        console.log(`You haven't read any pages today, you have ${d} pages left to read and ${b}.`);
    }
}

bookCalc(bookName, bookPageNum, bookPageReadToday, bookDailyLimit);type here
```

In my function i have several template literal strings I tried to change to a different syntax, example instead of ${c - b} to ${c} - ${b} but it just didn't work. I suspect this is a syntax issue.

Comment: could you rename the function arguments to something more useful. It'll help with your calculations - also, add to the question values you've entered

Comment: `if (c - d === 0 || c > d)` is the same as `if (c >= d)`

Comment: for example, if you've read 6 pages today, and the book has 1005 total pages, then `c - b` will will be `6 - 1005` - doesn't matter WHICH 6 pages you read

Comment: try to parse in Number/Integer value as by default it will be string before doing any operation

Comment: @Jaromand and everyone, thanks for the help and time to look at this. Will apply it to my code and learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Your problem is not a syntax problem but a **simple mathematical error**. The problem can be easily identified when we rename the function arguments to more useful (clear) names.

```
const bookCalc = (bookName, bookPageNum, bookPageReadToday, d) => {
    if (bookPageReadToday - bookDailyLimit === 0 || bookPageReadToday > bookDailyLimit) {
        console.log(`You have read your daily limit today for your book called ${bookName}, Well DONE!! you have ${bookPageReadToday - bookPageNum} left to read in total`);
    } else if (bookPageNum - bookPageReadToday > 0) {
        console.log(`you still have ${bookPageReadToday - bookDailyLimit} pages left to read today and ${bookPageReadToday - bookPageNum} pages to read in total.`);
    } else {
        console.log(`You haven't read any pages today, you have ${bookDailyLimit} pages left to read and ${bookPageNum}.`);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code with the renamed arguments, your **arguments are in wrong order**. For example, in the block of code after the first `if`, you calculate the "left to read in total" as

```
${bookPageReadToday - bookPageNum}
```

which gives you `20 - 100 = -80` if you input `bookPageReadToday=20` and `bookPageNum=100`.

The same mathematical error is in the block of code after the `else if`, where you calculate the "pages left to read today" as

```
${bookPageReadToday - bookDailyLimit}
```

which gives you `3 - 10 = -7` if you input `bookPageReadToday=3`, and in the "pages to read in total" which you calculate as

```
${bookPageReadToday - bookPageNum}
```

which gives you `3 - 100 = -97`.

### Solution

To get the desired positive number, **you should switch the two arguments** and calculate the value as

```
${bookPageNum - bookPageReadToday}
```

and

```
${bookDailyLimit - bookPageReadToday}
```

### Revised code

Using your original code with "unclear" arguments, the revised code should look like this

```
const bookCalc = (a, b, c, d) => {
    if (c - d === 0 || c > d) {
        console.log(`You have read your daily limit today for your book called ${a}, Well DONE!! you have ${b - c} left to read in total`);
    } else if (b - c > 0) {
        console.log(`you still have ${d - c} pages left to read today and ${b - c} pages to read in total.`);
    } else {
        console.log(`You haven't read any pages today, you have ${d} pages left to read and ${b}.`);
    }
}
```

### Additional recommendations

##### If statement

You can **simplify your if statement** (`if (c - d === 0 || c > d)`) to

```
if (c >= d)
```

##### Calculating values

Your code is repetitive (you evaluate `b - c` three times), and you calculate the values of remaining pages directly in the `console.log` outputs. This makes the code less clear and debugging is more complicated (as you can see in your problem). In your case, it would be better to **first calculate the values**, and then use them in the `console.log` outputs, e.g.:

```
const bookCalc = (a, b, c, d) => {
    const left_today = d - c
    const left_total = b - c
    if (c >= d) {
        console.log(`You have read your daily limit today for your book called ${a}, Well DONE!! you have ${left_total} left to read in total`);
    } else if (left_total > 0) {
        console.log(`you still have ${left_today} pages left to read today and ${left_total} pages to read in total.`);
    } else {
        console.log(`You haven't read any pages today, you have ${d} pages left to read and ${b}.`);
    }
}
```

Comment: i really appreciate the time you’ve taken to look at my code and break it down for me like this is is extremely clear and makes complete sense. Will definitely apply this going forward and learn from it. Wow you are amazing. Thanks you!

Comment: @Dlastman, you are welcome, and I am glad that the answer helped you :) Please consider accepting the answer so others in future know that this answer solved your problem.